# Flex works only on View component?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

There is no information about it on official docs. They just show examples with View component but without saying that applying flex to the Text component is wrong. 
This [article](https://freecontent.manning.com/in-depth-styling-with-react-native-and-flexbox/) says:

> Flexbox layout’s only available for use on View components.

But when I test this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, padding:10,}}>
        <Text style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          Some Text
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[snack](https://snack.expo.io/ByJ_H!zSL)

So why `flex:1` works on Text component if this is not supporting?

Comment: Maybe it means `display: flex` only works on view components but the `flex` property works on children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that it is supported. In my personal experience I have seen it worked with `Text`, `TextInput`, `Image`, `TouchableOpacity` and so on. If the element is an element that can be displayed within or among other items on the screen layout, it should be affected by `flex`.

However whether to use it like that or not would be a better question. I think that this is a good example of *separation of concerns*. `Text` is here to display a text and to style it. If we want to adjust the layout, we should use `View`: wrap your `Text` with `View` and apply all necessary layout and positioning styles. This will eliminate all overhead confusion about what each element's core responsibilities are, and when it comes to ease of coding, will also allow us to always know that for layout - we refer to `View`, and for displaying text - we refer to `Text`. This uniformity will make your debugging, team work, and legacy work, much easier to perceive.

Answer (score 1):

The source that you mention might be inaccurate. You can certainly apply `flex` properties to a `<Text>` component (at least there's no documentation that says otherwise). However, doing so is not something common or recommended.

React Native docs describe [`<Text>`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/text) as:

> A React component for displaying text.

And [`<View>`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/view) components as:

> The most fundamental component for building a UI, View is a container that supports layout with flexbox, style, some touch handling, and accessibility controls

Interesting fact: React Native leverages the [Yoga Layout Engine](https://yogalayout.com/) to build layouts with ease.